# unsolved inclusion #include <bb/cascades/Application>

Tags: blackberry-10

The momentics IDe for BB10 has encountered a problem or at least I believe that al my inclusions appears as unsolved. when I compile the app it compile correctly and everything works pretty well.  But the problem is that I need to import some libraryes like #include  and as long as this libreries are shown as insolved inclusion I cannot declare any object of those types.

Does any one know what can be this and how to solve it.

**Things done berofe:**

I've tried cleaning the workspace and creating a new project and also the new project works perfectly, also I've tried going to configure add and and some libraries. this works but only works for specific libraries, not at all for  libraries.

**Edit 1:** As I saw on other posts, I've reinstalled the 10.1 sdk that is the one I need, but no luck

Comment: What library do you use? Take care not to forget the .pro file and add  something like "LIBS += -lbbplatformbbm"

Comment: I'm using 10.1.0.4828

Comment: Also as I know it was supposed that the BB/cascades/ was with the project creation, I've created a hello world problem but the inclusion still unresolved.

Comment: I was wondering about the Qt lib you use. Do you uses specific functionnalities like maps, bbm, security, cards, geoloc, etc.... Which inclusion does not work?

Comment: is Strange, no basic inclusion works, I've created a new hello project and all the inclusion cannot be resolved. despite of it the project compiles well and also runs well, the fact that is annoying for now is that the lint is only working when I clean the project so if you mistype a variable or something you less time reviewing and cleaning to much. is not a happy time.

Answer (score 0):

In the Workspace's Project Explorer pane, right click the project, and then select Build Configurations -> Set Active -> Simulator-Debug (Just to be sure.)

From menus, Window -> Preferences. In the Preferences dialog's left pane choose C/C++ -> Indexer.

To get intellisense to work when authoring well before making builds, under Indexer options, check boxes Index source files not included in the build, index unused headers, index source and header files opened in editor. And under indexing strategy check both boxes, automatic update and update after every file save.

Finally, under Build configuration for the indexer select the Use active build configuration option (Just to be sure.).

**For class declaration in header file, the erratic feedback from IDE will disappear (as of Momentics 2.1.2) only after cpp file for implementation, that includes the header is saved.**

If modifying header, after setting up as above, right-clicking on the project in Workspace pane -> Index -> Rebuild should work.